# How to create a content type that incorporates a batch upload and body field, with a gallery output

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, media

I'm working on a client site that needs to include event recaps with a gallery of photos for each event under the text recap and event results. They're not very tech savvy so the standard method of creating a view through individually uploading images is going to be too complicated for them, So what I want for them to be able to do

Log in > Click add content > Click event recap or similar > Add a title and a date > Upload a thumbnail image > Put in their event results, who won what etc, probably just in a wysiwyg field > Batch upload images > Click save

And then for the front end, have a teaser sorted by date under an event recaps parent menu link, and on click the 'page' itself with the text recap, the thumbnail and the images in gallery format.

Is there some way I can combine taxonomy, views, and a batch upload module to make this come together for a less tech friendly user or a module that already does something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an image field accept multiple values and set its display to be gallery using one of that two modules [galleryformatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/galleryformatter), [field_slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow)

And build a view list nodes ordered by the date field selecting one image image from the image field as a thumbnail (using relationships) by setting the delta to be just 1 [image]

take a look at [how-control-display-multi-value-fields-drupal](http://www.webwash.net/articles/how-control-display-multi-value-fields-drupal)